# remove big space between equations in split environment

Tags: spacing, equations, split, vertical-spacing

I am new to latex and struggling to remove big space between the equations and between equation and text. I am using \documentclass{extarticle} and the equations I am writing are big which looks like

```
\begin{equation}

\begin{split}

Long equations taking more than half page

\end{split}

\end{equation}
```

I think that latex is taking all the equations as one piece and that's why when half page is left, the equations are shifted to next page. (I am using split command, because it aligns the equations easily using '&') Please tell me how to get rid of this problem.

The actual code is

```
 \section{Diffeomorphism}
$L_o = m(\dot{x}^2)^\frac{1}{2}$\\[10pt]
$\dot{x}^2 = \dot{x_\mu}\dot{x^\mu} = \dot{x_0}\dot{x^0}+\dot{x_1}\dot{x^1}+.....................+\dot{x_{D-1}}\dot{x^{D-1}}$\\[15pt]
Action $S = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\tau \; m(\dot{x}^2)^\frac{1}{2}$\\[10pt]
Diffeomorphism\\
$\tau \rightarrow \tau' = f(\tau) \simeq \tau -\epsilon(\tau)$\\
$f(\tau) = finite\; at\; \tau =0$\\
$f(\tau) \rightarrow 0$ as $\tau \rightarrow \pm \infty$\\
Action remains invariant under Diffeomorphism Transformations. We can prove it as follows:\\
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
S' & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\tau' \; m\left[\left(\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau'}\right)\left(\frac{dx_\mu}{d\tau'}\right)\right]^\frac{1}{2}\\[10pt]
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d\tau'}{d\tau}d\tau \; m\left[\left(\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\right)\left(\frac{d\tau}{d\tau'}\right)\left(\frac{dx_\mu}{d\tau}\right)\left(\frac{d\tau}{d\tau'}\right)\right]^\frac{1}{2}\\[10pt]
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\tau \left(\frac{d\tau'}{d\tau}\right)\left(\frac{d\tau}{d\tau'}\right) \; m\left[\left(\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\right)\left(\frac{dx_\mu}{d\tau}\right)\right]^\frac{1}{2}\\[10pt]
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\tau \; m(\dot{x}^2)^\frac{1}{2}\\[10pt]
&=S
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

The output is

[image]

Comment: I don't think that `split` can be broken across pages. You might try with `align` (requires several `\notag` commands, though) and `\displaybreak` at the appropriate spot.

Comment: Hi @sawan kt, are you  breaking lines with `\\ `? It hangs on your equations, but other environments such as `align`-family, `array`-family might be useful.

Comment: yes inside align I am using \\ to break lines @FHZ

Comment: if you provide an example then people wil be able to give specific help, without an example  it is harder, although if you use align  rather than equation and split then the display can have a page break as egreg says

Comment: When I am copying my code and pasting on this site, it is looking ugly, please tell me how to do it @DavidCarlisle

Comment: you can highlight the code and use the `{}` button in the editor, which marks a code section by indenting or put `\`\`\`` before and after

Comment: Thankyou sir @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, no, you can't break an equation inside an split environment. One you can use is align. Try using the allowdisplaybreaks command.

```
\begingroup
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{align}
    ....
\end{align}
\endgroup
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I have given to you a good answer and I have followed your request but I have written everything on one page. Here I add my MWE example with some additional packages like `parskip` to justify the text and I have improved some commands.

```
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
\section{Diffeomorphism}
$L_0 = m(\dot{x}^2)^\frac{1}{2}$.
\vskip2pt
\[\dot{x}^2 = \dot{x_\mu}\dot{x}^\mu = \dot{x_0}\dot{x}^0+\dot{x_1}\dot{x}^1+\cdots\cdots\cdots+\dot{x}_{D-1}\dot{x}^{D-1}.\]
\vskip2pt
\textbf{Action} $S = \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\tau \; m(\dot{x}^2)^\frac{1}{2}$.
\vskip2pt
\textbf{Diffeomorphism}
$\tau \rightarrow \tau' = f(\tau) \simeq \tau -\epsilon(\tau)$.

$f(\tau) =\text{ finite at }\tau =0$.

$f(\tau) \rightarrow 0$ as $\tau \rightarrow \pm \infty$.

Action remains invariant under \textsl{Diffeomorphism Transformations}. We can prove it as follows:
\vspace{-.2cm}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
S' & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\tau' \; m\left[\left(\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau'}\right)\left(\frac{dx_\mu}{d\tau'}\right)\right]^\frac{1}{2}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\frac{d\tau'}{d\tau}\right) d\tau \; m\left[\left(\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\right)\left(\frac{d\tau}{d\tau'}\right)\left(\frac{dx_\mu}{d\tau}\right)\left(\frac{d\tau}{d\tau'}\right)\right]^\frac{1}{2}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\tau \left(\frac{d\tau'}{d\tau}\right)\left(\frac{d\tau}{d\tau'}\right) \; m\left[\left(\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\right)\left(\frac{dx_\mu}{d\tau}\right)\right]^\frac{1}{2}\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\tau \; m(\dot{x}^2)^\frac{1}{2}\\
&=S
\end{split}
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this really helped. Thankyou